# Is there a way to show a user-defined postgresql enumerated type definition?

Tags: postgresql, enums

Let's say we've defined a postgresql type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS ENUM('foo', 'bar');
```

Is there any way to show the type definition after creation ?

I would expect "\d my_type" to show me "ENUM('foo', 'bar')", but it says :

```
Did not find any relation named "my_type"
```

The pg_type table doesn't seem to give enough information.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It's \dT you're after, but it doesn't give it as a "CREATE" statement. You use \dD for domains.

```
\dT+ action.action_status
                          List of data types
 Schema |         Name         | Internal name | Size | Elements | Description 
--------+----------------------+---------------+------+----------+-------------
 action | action.action_status | action_status | 4    | pending +| 
        |                      |               |      | live    +| 
        |                      |               |      | done    +| 
        |                      |               |      | notdone  | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of "You use \dD for domains."

Comment: Domains and types are different things. You use \dD for domains and \dT for types.

Comment: Ok, I see. "A domain is essentially a data type with optional constraints (restrictions on the allowed set of values)."

Comment: It took me a bit to realize that what I really wanted was `\dT+ my_enum;`.

Answer (score 158):

Check this:

```
select enum_range(null::my_type)
```

I think this is a much simpler solution :).

Comment: I like this one for its simplicity. The top rated works by all means... but this one does too. :)

Comment: I like this one.  The \d syntax didn't work in dbeaver or pgadmin, but the pure SQL in portable

Comment: Works in PostgreSQL 8.3.11

Comment: What do I type instead of `null:my_type` if my table is called `users` and the column `status` and the enum type is `enum_user_status`? I tried all combinations I could think of but got nothing.

Comment: @exebook I'm way late, but I used `null::enum_user_status` (obviously I used my enum name instead of `enum_user_status`). The table/colum the enum is used in wasn't involved.

Answer (score 15):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-enum.html)

> `enum_range` ( `anyenum` ) → `anyarray`
>
> Returns all values of the input enum type in an ordered array.

To also get the schema:

```sql
SELECT typnamespace::regnamespace AS "schema", typname
     , enum_range(null::my_enum_type)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_type 
WHERE  typname = 'my_enum_type';
```

Returns:

```
 schema | typname      | enum_labels
--------+--------------+-------------
 public | my_enum_type | {foo,bar}
```

You can also get the SQL `CREATE` statement from a dump file. Cheapest from a schema-only dump with `pg_dump --schema-only ...`.

Or simply use [**pgAdmin**](https://pgadmin.org/). Select the object in the `object browser` and its create script is displayed in the `SQL pane`.

Comment: Note that you need to enable viewing types in `pgAdmin` by default: File → Options → Browser and checking `Types`.

Comment: actually as of version 1.18.1 you can find that option in File -> Options -> Display.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.typname
FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_attribute a ON c.oid = a.attrelid JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
WHERE c.relname = 'your_type';
```

The tricky part was that simply selecting * from these views one does not get OIDs in the results.

Answer (score -1):

using [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35510/212793), I've archived the goal to mimic the 'CREATE TYPE' in PgAdmin & PgBackup

```
WITH types AS (
    SELECT n.nspname,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS obj_name,
            CASE
                WHEN t.typrelid != 0 THEN CAST ( 'tuple' AS pg_catalog.text )
                WHEN t.typlen < 0 THEN CAST ( 'var' AS pg_catalog.text )
                ELSE CAST ( t.typlen AS pg_catalog.text )
                END AS obj_type,
            coalesce ( pg_catalog.obj_description ( t.oid, 'pg_type' ), '' ) AS description
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
        WHERE ( t.typrelid = 0
                OR ( SELECT c.relkind = 'c'
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                        WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid ) )
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el
                        WHERE el.oid = t.typelem
                        AND el.typarray = t.oid )
            AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
            AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
            AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
),
cols AS (
    SELECT n.nspname::text AS schema_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) AS obj_name,
            a.attname::text AS column_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type ( a.atttypid, a.atttypmod ) AS data_type,
            a.attnotnull AS is_required,
            a.attnum AS ordinal_position,
            pg_catalog.col_description ( a.attrelid, a.attnum ) AS description
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t
            ON a.attrelid = t.typrelid
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON ( n.oid = t.typnamespace )
        JOIN types
            ON ( types.nspname = n.nspname
                AND types.obj_name = pg_catalog.format_type ( t.oid, NULL ) )
        WHERE a.attnum > 0
            AND NOT a.attisdropped
)
SELECT 'CREATE TYPE ' || cols.schema_name || '.' || cols.obj_name || E' AS (\n    ' ||
pg_catalog.array_to_string (ARRAY( 
    SELECT cols.column_name || ' ' || cols.data_type AS col_num_typ
    FROM cols
    WHERE cols.obj_name='my_user_data_type'
    ORDER BY cols.schema_name,
            cols.obj_name,
            cols.ordinal_position ), E',\n    '
    ) || E'\n);'
AS cre_typ
FROM cols
WHERE cols.obj_name='my_user_data_type'
LIMIT 1
```

and run it under psql with this command to have only the SQL code :

`\t\a\g\a\t`